# How can I remove an axis on click in Plotly for parcoords?

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, parallel-coordinates

From the documentation, I've found 
[custom buttons](https://plot.ly/r/custom-buttons/#methods)
and [click events](https://plot.ly/r/click-events/#binding-to-click-events). However, I can't figure out how to pair these to make it so when I click on a y axis in my parallel coordinates plot, it deletes that axis.

edit: What I tried: 
It seems that I can choose dots, but not lines.

```
plot_ly(partial, type = 'parcoords', 
line = list(color = partial$freq,
colorscale = 'Jet',
showscale = TRUE,
reversescale = TRUE,
cmin = min_freq,
cmax = max_freq),
dimensions = interactiveList
) %>%
layout(title=name) %>%
onRender("
function(el, x) {
  console.log('entered');
  console.log(el);
  el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
    // d.points is an array of objects which, in this case,
    // is length 1 since the click is tied to 1 point.
    console.log('lalala');
    var pt = d.points[0];
    var url = pt.data.text[pt.pointNumber];
    // DISCLAIMER: this won't work from RStudio
  console.log('hello');
    window.open(url);
  });
  el.on('plotly_selected', function(d) {
            console.log('selected');
  });
}
```

")

Comment: Maybe you can paste some code that you tried?